# Apache spark mlib lda java create word/document frequencies list

Tags: java, apache-spark, lda

I'm using apache spark's mlib version 1.4.0 to perform a latent dirichelet analysis on a text document in which each line represents a tweet.

Taking the example from the [project](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda) I discovered that I first need to produce something like a term/document frequency list.

My first question is whether I'm right to assume that in the project's example the [file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_lda_data.txt) each row represents a term/word and each column a document and the cell numbers the counts.

My second question then is how do I produce such text file or directly a JavaRDD object? 
I'm able to get the word count for all tweets in the file with:

```
    JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile(path);
    JavaRDD<String> words = data.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String> () {   public Iterable<String> call(String s) { return Arrays.asList(s.split("")); }});

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
       public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) { return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1); } });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) { return a + b; }
```

Thanks for any hints or comments!

Comment: The [scala LDA example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/LDAExample.scala#L188) contains a lot more features, including the one you are looking for. Check out the preprocess method.

Comment: `sc.textFile` breaks the file into lines.  The next step is to split the line into words, so is that a blank string in `Arrays.asList(s.split(""))` or is a single whitespace `Arrays.asList(s.split(" "))` ? It matters.  Splitting on empty string will probably split into chars, not words.   Personally I would use some other regex there, perhaps `\W` or `\b`

Answer (score 0):

If your documents are seperated out on a per-file basis, a simple option to construct a document - word frequency list would be to use the `wholeTextFiles` api along with `flatMapValues`.

Or if your documents are on a per-line basis you can do pretty much what the example code was doing.

Comment: Is she right to assume when she says "that in the project's example file, each row represents a term/word and each column a document and the cell numbers the counts."